# Jekyll-Redirect-From Redirects Not Being Applied

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm contributing to an open source project that has its documentation built in Jekyll and hosted on Github Pages. I'm trying to add a redirect in the documentation, so I've forked it and am using jekyll-redirect-from in the fork. However, the redirect simply doesn't seem to be applied. That is, the jekyll build folder doesn't contain any static file to hold the `<meta redirect>` html that jekyll-redirect-from is supposed to generate. Instead, when I visite the URI that's supposed to be redirected, I just get a 404.

I've followed all the steps in the jekyll-redirect-from docs, including:

- Adding jekyll-redirect-from to the Gemfile ([code](https://github.com/ethanresnick/json-api-1/blob/gh-pages/Gemfile))
- Adding it to my _config.yml file ([code](https://github.com/ethanresnick/json-api-1/blob/site-tweaks/_config.yml#L15))
- Adding the `redirect_from` key to my page's front matter ([code](https://github.com/ethanresnick/json-api-1/commit/3b20684f49eee217336a3cc65a1d5cfaed4bc078#diff-26e38355b69056b0db1c2b1c612241b2R4))

I'm using jekyll 2.5.0 and jekyll-redirect-from 0.8.0 (the full gemfile is linked above). I'm building the project with bundler (using `bundle exec jekyll serve`), which is how the project's always been built.

Jekyll isn't showing any errors—the static file that should hold the redirect simply doesn't show up.

I can't for the life of me figure out the problem. Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, or maybe there's some sort of subtle incompatibility in my dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

D'oh. The issue was that the `safe` option needed to be set to `false` for the plugin to run. This tripped me up because I know Github Pages sets `safe` to false as well, and yet `jekyll-redirect-from` generally runs there. But that appears to be because GH Pages has made an explicit exception to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had:

```yaml
redirect_from: /a/path/
redirect_from: /other/path
```

And repeated directives don't work like that in YAML.

Instead, it should be:

```yaml
redirect_from:
  - /a/path/
  - /other/path
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this took me 2 hours to figure out!

I was using:

```
redirect-from
```

instead of the correct form:

```
redirect_from
```

It's an underscore, not a hyphen!

Hopefully, no one else will feel my pain.